# Dynamically write a .feature file in eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse, jira, cucumber-junit

My requirement is to import test details which will contain the Cucumber BDD script i.e. Given...When...Then... etc. The same exported content I need to write into my feature file and execute it. The exported test details are from JIRA which contains the Cucumber scenario description. Though I am not sure still on the format of the exported test details, it may be a .cs or .java file.. Kindly answer me the part of dynamically writing/creating a feature file in eclipse. Be informed that the requirement is not for parameterization of variables within the feature file, the complete feature file needs to be dynamically created in a specific location in Eclipse, which further drives my StepDefinition.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few commercial add-ons that support adding BDD scenarios to JIRA issues and that integrate with other BDD to tools to export and run those scenarios.

For example take a look at:

- [Behave Pro](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/pro.behave.hosted/cloud/overview) (supports JIRA Cloud only at the moment)
- [qTest](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.qasymphony.qtestscenario/cloud/overview) - (supports both JIRA Server and Cloud)

Other than that you can probably script a solution using either:

- the [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) add-on (commercial) (supports JIRA Server only)
- a script in a language of your preference that uses the [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/) (works both with JIRA Server and Cloud)

Comment: Thank you for the response!!.. I can use rest api to export it from JIRA, that's fine.. But my question is not that. Suppose I have the CUCUMBER script in an excel file and I hv a .feature file in my eclipse. How do I populate this script which is there in excel into my .feature file in Eclipse.

Comment: You'll have to write a script that will read from your excel file and update your .feature file. You could use Groovy (or another language that runs on a java vm) and use the Apache POI library. Or if you want to write it using another language, just look for a suitable library for that one. Or save your Excel file as a csv and just parse that.

Comment: Thank you Glenn. Suppose I trigger a URL(JIRA API) and have the json text in my browser. Is there any way I can capture the same in .cs or .java file and use this file as an input to my .feature file.

Comment: Jersey provides the reference implementation of the JAX-RS (REST) specification for java. So you can start with looking for an example of how to write a java REST client using Jersey. The documentation for the Jersey client api is available here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html